# How to restart the django server from views.py for localization changes in python code to take affect

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am new to python and django. I have started a translation project. Where i am letting the user to choose the language from UI. Post request from language_localize.html page will call my views.py method language_localize.

```
def language_localize(request):
print "inside language_localize.."
if request.method == "GET":
    print "inside  GET request"
    _id = request.GET.get('language')
    print "_id="+str(_id)
    if _id == None :
        request.session['django_language'] = 'en'
        print "Language set to English"

    elif str(_id) == "en":
        request.session['django_language'] = 'en'
        print "Language set to English"

    elif str(_id) == "de":
        request.session['django_language'] = 'de'
        print "Language set to German"

    elif str(_id) == "fr":
        request.session['django_language'] = 'fr'
        print "Language set to French"


return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('homepage'))
```

this would change my UI(User Interface) contents to display translated strings. all frameworks for translation are done.

But each time i change the language I need to restart the server by pressing Cntrl+c and executing "python2.7 manage runserver 0.0.0.0:8060" on console for the changes to take affect.

Are there any python commands to restart the server, so that i can use in my language_localize method to restart the server automatically? or are there some other ways for changes to take affect on UI?

By the way, I have locale/ directory,views.py under the same app directory. and also i have a text_translation.py which contains all my strings with ugettext tag for conversion. Each time to display a page, urls.py will call particular method under views.py and views.py method gets the string from text_translation.py and renders that to html file using a variable 'params' and displays.

I am using python2.7 and django1.5.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the content of your template file? It should not require a restart. I can see that you are storing the locale in the session. But are you using the session values to render the right template?

Comment: Hi @manu Now I am using django's default method to select language as suggested by bruno desthuilliers. But still facing the same problem. can you just read the comment i wrote for bruno desthuilliers's answer, that includes my current status of code. Using text_translation.py provides back end strings(added ugettext tag). My views.py methods just reads those strings and renders those to respective html page. At the html page i am using Example: " {{dns_text.portal}}" kind of tags to display strings. but on selection of language only strings on html page with trans tag are getting translated.

Comment: So in order to get a page with complete translation still i need to restart the server. Strings coming from back end  [text_translation.py-->views.py-->html page] are still not getting translated. Where have i gone wrong?

Comment: You can use trans tag with those things like this. `{% trans dns_text.portal %}`

Comment: Does this solve your problem?

Comment: @manu Yes using 'trans' tag is one solution, it works for me. But it is for the strings which are on html page. Most of my strings were coming from backend, that too from text_translation.py. So using both 'lazy translation' and 'trans' tag solved my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Used 'Lazy translation' at the back end to load the strings to HTML pages  only when the request has come.

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

This solved my problem. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the (squared) wheel when everything you need is already part of the framework and well documented ?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/#internationalization-and-localization

Comment: Hi @bruno desthuilliers , Your suggestions helped me.Instead of using my method now I am using default Django's django.views.i18n.set_language() method and form as mentioned in documents. Now I have a form to select language.But onselection of languages HTML contents only with {%trans %} tag are getting translated.I have most of the strings at 'text_translation.py' with 'ugettext' tag which I am rendering to html from respective views.py method. At Html i am using Ex:"{{dns_text.portal}}" kind of tags to display strings.These strings still requires restart of the server to take affect.Help me